# Creating a table with JavaScript with a column and a row fixed

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I'm trying to create a table manipulating the DOM with JS, my goal is to create a table with a row on top with the abcedary and a column on the side with numbers, while the midle cells remain empty.

Something like this (please excuse my Paint skills):
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvoEf.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Yal.jpg)

I've created the letters row and the numbers column with a for loops, but I'm struggling with the positioning of the column, I've put it in place with a display grid but I'm aware that's not the proper way to do it.

My other problem are the rest of the cells. I don't know how to position them between the other two and I've gotten to a point where I think I'm complicating myself too much and there's probably a very simple solution in front of me but I can't see it. Please any advice would be very welcome.

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // Get the first element in the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    // Create a table
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');

    
    // Create a table-head
    var abecedary = [' ','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    var tableHead = document.createElement('THEAD');
    
    // Append the table head to the table
    table.appendChild(tableHead);
    
    var trA = document.createElement('TR');
    trA.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTR');
    // Append the rows to the head
    tableHead.appendChild(trA);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < abecedary.length; i++) {
        // Create the rows
        var th = document.createElement('TH');
        th.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTH');
        th.innerHTML = abecedary[i];
        // Append them to the rows
        trA.appendChild(th);
    }

    // Create a table-body
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    
    // Append the table body to the table
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    
    // Create the rows
    var trL = document.createElement('TR');
    trL.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTR');
    // Append the rows to the body
    tableBody.appendChild(trL);
    // Loop to create the cells and rows
    for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTD');
        td.innerHTML = i;
        // Append them to the rows
        trL.appendChild(td);
    }

    // Loop to create the cells and rows
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        // Create the rows
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        // Append the rows to the body
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        // Create the cells
        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++){
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            td.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            // Append them to the rows
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    // Append the table to the body
    body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.lettersTR {
    display: grid;
}

table th {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
} 
 
table td {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
} 

table td:hover {
    background-color: violet;
} 

table td:focus {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Spreadsheet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using two separate loops to create rows/cells.  The second loop - headed `Loop to create the cells and rows`, should be nested within the one headed `Create the rows` and you just create cells to append to the same row.  So, immediately after where you've created the cell with `i` as the contents,  create another loop to create new cells and append those to the row.

Comment: In addition to that, your css includes: .`lettersTR {display: grid;}` which will confuse the table layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are trying to achieve?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // Get the first element in the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    // Create a table
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');

    
    // Create a table-head
    var abecedary = [' ','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    var tableHead = document.createElement('THEAD');
    
    // Append the table head to the table
    table.appendChild(tableHead);
    
    var trA = document.createElement('TR');
    trA.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTR');
    // Append the rows to the head
    tableHead.appendChild(trA);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < abecedary.length; i++) {
        // Create the rows
        var th = document.createElement('TH');
        th.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTH');
        th.innerHTML = abecedary[i];
        // Append them to the rows
        trA.appendChild(th);
    }

    // Create a table-body
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    
    // Append the table body to the table
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    
    // Loop to create the cells and rows
    for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
      // Create the rows
      var trL = document.createElement('TR');
      trL.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTR');
      
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTD');
        td.innerHTML = i;
        trL.appendChild(td);
        for (var j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
          trL.appendChild(td);
        }
      // Append the rows to the body
      tableBody.appendChild(trL);
    }

    // Append the table to the body
    body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.lettersTR {
/*    display: grid;*/
}

table th {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
} 
 
table td {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
} 

table td:hover {
    background-color: violet;
} 

table td:focus {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

I've nested to two blocks of code that create rows and cells and commented out the style that uses `grid` as that does not really work within a table row properly.

Comment: I've also updated the code to output 26 cells per row - your code has 13.  I'm not sure if that is a typo or if the code should be doing something else?

Comment: It was indeed a typo, this solves my problem beautifully, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to split the problem into smaller chunks, by creating functions to handle cells, rows and the table. This makes the code easier to debug and maintain.

Here it is an example of how you can handle it:

```js
function paintCell(isHeader = false, isEditable = false, cellContent = '') {
  // create cell
  const tableCell = isHeader && document.createElement('TH') || document.createElement('TD');

  // set cell style
  if (isHeader) {
    tableCell.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTH');
  } else {
    tableCell.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTD');
  }

  // set cell editable
  if (!isHeader && isEditable) {
    tableCell.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')
  }

  // set cell content
  tableCell.innerText = cellContent;

  return tableCell;
}

function paintRow(cols, isHeader, firstCellContent = '') {
  if (cols.length < 1) return null;

  // create row
  const tableRow = document.createElement('TR');

  // set row style
  isHeader
    ?
    tableRow.setAttribute('class', 'abecedaryTR') :
    tableRow.setAttribute('class', 'lettersTR');

  // set row content
  cols.forEach((col, index) => {
    const cell = isHeader ?
      paintCell(isHeader, false, col) :
      index === 0 ?
      paintCell(isHeader, false, firstCellContent) : // or paintCell(isHeader, true, firstCellContent), if you want the first cell to be editable too
      paintCell(isHeader, true);
    tableRow.appendChild(cell)
  });

  return tableRow;
}

function paintTable(tableEl, cols, numOfRows) {
  if (!tableEl || cols.length < 1) return null;

  // create row container
  const tableHeader = document.createElement('THEAD');
  const tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
    const isHeader = i === 0;
    const row = paintRow(cols, isHeader, i);
    isHeader
      ?
      tableHeader.appendChild(row) :
      tableBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  tableEl.appendChild(tableHeader);
  tableEl.appendChild(tableBody);
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Get the first element in the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  // Create a table
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');

  // Create a table-head
  var abecedary = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

  paintTable(table, abecedary, 13);

  // Append the table to the body
  body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*.lettersTR {
  display: grid;
}*/

table th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

table td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

table td:hover {
  background-color: violet;
}

table td:focus {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```